# Matplotlib can't save eps format figure if include LaTex codes.(Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Here are my codes:

```
mpl.rcParams.update({'font.size': 18, 'font.weight': 'bold'})
mpl.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 7))

some data process
plot the data use pyplot.plot(x, y)

plt.legend(handles=[legend1,legend2,legend3,legend4], loc=8, numpoints=1)
plt.xlabel(r'$k_{s}$')
plt.ylabel(r'$P(k_{s})$')
plt.xlim(0.95, 100)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('fig3.eps', div=300, format='eps')
```

Above code would raise a **TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly** when calling savefig method. The expected figure can be showed in my Jupyter notebook but doesn't save eps file really. However, other format such as png, jpeg and pdf seems work.

I tried to delete `mpl.rc('text', usetex=True)` and remove all LaTex codes, then the exception disappear.

My matplotlib version is: 1.5.1 and python version is 3.5

I can't find any useful information on google or matplotlib official docs. Please give me a hand. Thanks all of you!

**Update**
I write a simple example, things don't change.

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mpl.rcParams.update({'font.size': 18, 'font.weight': 'bold'})
mpl.rc('text', usetex=True)

x = np.arange(10)
y = x

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel(r'$k_{s}$', fontweight='bold')
plt.ylabel(r'$P(k_{s})$', fontweight='bold')

plt.savefig('figtest.eps',format='eps', dpi=300)
```

Expected result show in my jupyter notebook, but it didn't save the fig to my disk.

Comment: format='eps is missing a quote? -> format='eps'

Comment: Sorry. I amend it. This would raise a syntax error rather than TypeError.

Comment: The code runs fine for me for random `x` and `y` variables. I suggest you to modify your post to make a minimal complete [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the error you encounter.

Comment: @Vlas Sokolov: Thank, I update the question. I almostly sure that is latex label string raise this exception, It seems we can not use latex code in a eps file. but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @yangxg there's nothing wrong with the code. Your new example works for me with matplotlib version 2.0.0b4.

Comment: @Vlas Sokolov Python version you used is py3? Maybe I should upgrade my matplotlib,. Thank you very much!

Comment: @yangxg yes, it was 3.5.2.